# Browser opens up blank and Laravel Dusk does not continue with tests on Ubuntu with Laravel Valet

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, laravel-dusk, laravel-valet

Dusk Version: 6.17
Laravel Version: 8.5
PHP Version: 7.4.3
Database Driver & Version:mysql 8.0.26

Description:
I am running laravel on Ubuntu along with laravel valet. My local domain is http://www.amlsuite24.test.
I have installed Laravel Dusk with chrome driver version 92.0.4515.107 and have chromium-browser version 92.0.4515.131 installed.

My DuskTestCase is as below:
[image]

And my APP URL in .env as below:

[image]

I can confirm that the chromedriver is able to start by running the bin file:

[image]

When i try to run the example test provided, using php artisan dusk the chromium browser opens up blank and the command seems stuck:

[image]

[image]

Also a new chromium window seems to open every 30s or so

Any help would be appreciated, already went through the below posts:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/can-i-run-laravel-dusk-on-my-forge-server#reply=327364
https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/6

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that i needed to install google chrome and not chromium-browser.
If anyone else is having the same issue the below provided the answer for me:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/installing-laravel-dusk-failed-to-connect-on-localhost-port-9515-connection-refused?page=1
[image]